# Spock mock calling real method of mocked class

Tags: java, spock

I have Spock integration tests for testing my Java app. For one of the methods, the call is going to the real method 'bMethod()', instead of the stubbed valued being returned. It works fine for another method 'aMethd()', and the stubbed value is returned and the actual method is not called. Both these methods are in same class, Calc. Is there a way to investigate what Spock is doing and why?

```
public interface CalcIntf {
  public int aMethod(int a, int b);      
  public int bMethod(int a, int b, int c);
}

MyTestSpec extends Specification {
    def "aMethod test"() {
        given:
          ...
          CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
          calcIntf.aMethod(_,_) >> { return 100; }
        when:
          //service call
        then:
          // asserts go here
    }

    def "bMethod test"() {
        given:
          ...
          CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
          calcIntf.bMethod(_,_,_) >> { return 100; }
        when:
          // service call
        then:
          // asserts go here
    }
}
```

Comment: There's a couple of things here - when stubbing aMethod and bMethod you need to do >> 100 rather than returning a closure

Comment: Also, m1 and m2 don't take any arguments

Comment: Also math has a Real calc hard coded into it so there's no way of setting a stub instead

Comment: Hi Prakash - I've put all the comments into a single coherent answer :-)

Comment: Regarding how to investigate - usually by debugging. And especially checking that objects you have stubbed are really your stubs when the real code is executing ie, when at a breakpoint in Math, make sure that calc is 'Mock for CalcIntf called calcIntf'. I think I'm your case you would see it is an instance of  Calc.

Answer (score 2):

#### Original code with minimal fixes

So first I made `m1` and `m2` return `int` instead of `void`. Then at least you can check the results. Then I also made sure those methods are called correctly without parameters, as Chris already mentioned. So for now the code looks like this:

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62269054

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
  def "testing addition using aMethod"() {
    given:
    Math math = new Math()
    CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
    calcIntf.aMethod(_, _) >> { return 123 }
    expect:
    math.m1() == 123
  }

  def "testing addition using bMethod"() {
    given:
    Math math = new Math()
    CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
    calcIntf.bMethod(_, _, _) >> { return 456 }
    expect:
    math.m2() == 456
  }

  interface CalcIntf {
    int aMethod(int a, int b)

    int bMethod(int a, int b, int c)
  }

  static class Calc implements CalcIntf {
    int aMethod(int a, int b) {
      return a + b
    }

    int bMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
      return a + b + c
    }
  }

  static class Math {
    Calc calc = new Calc()

    int m1() {
      calc.aMethod(1, 2)
    }

    int m2() {
      calc.bMethod(1, 2, 3)
    }
  }
}
```

Of course, the tests fail:

```
Condition not satisfied:

math.m1() == 123
|    |    |
|    3    false
...

Condition not satisfied:

math.m2() == 456
|    |    |
|    6    false
...
```

The reason for the failure is that you did not inject your mock anywhere, but `Math` uses a hard-coded `Calc` instance via `Calc calc = new Calc()`.

#### Make tests pass

So we need a way to inject the mock, e.g. via constructor or setter. You also should change the field type from `Calc` to `CalcIntf` because otherwise it is impossible to inject an interface mock. Why create interfaces if you don't use them in your code but code against concrete subclasses?

```groovy
package de.scrum_master.stackoverflow.q62269054

import spock.lang.Specification

class MyTestSpec extends Specification {
  def "testing addition using aMethod"() {
    given:
    CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
    calcIntf.aMethod(_, _) >> { return 123 }
    Math math = new Math(calcIntf)
    expect:
    math.m1() == 123
  }

  def "testing addition using bMethod"() {
    given:
    CalcIntf calcIntf = Mock(CalcIntf)
    calcIntf.bMethod(_, _, _) >> { return 456 }
    Math math = new Math(calcIntf)
    expect:
    math.m2() == 456
  }

  interface CalcIntf {
    int aMethod(int a, int b)

    int bMethod(int a, int b, int c)
  }

  static class Calc implements CalcIntf {
    int aMethod(int a, int b) {
      return a + b
    }

    int bMethod(int a, int b, int c) {
      return a + b + c
    }
  }

  static class Math {
    CalcIntf calcIntf

    Math(CalcIntf calcIntf) {
      this.calcIntf = calcIntf
    }

    int m1() {
      calcIntf.aMethod(1, 2)
    }

    int m2() {
      calcIntf.bMethod(1, 2, 3)
    }
  }
}
```

#### Your described test behaviour

So now the tests pass, but they do not reproduce the behaviour you described:

> For one of the methods, the call is going to the real method 'bMethod()', instead of the stubbed valued being returned.

I can imagine one reason why this would happen: The method you want to stub is `final`, which means that the dynamic proxy implementing the mock cannot override it and thus not stub it. But this is a completely different case from the one you describe here in your code.

See? Your sample code is completely useless if it does not reproduce the problem, which is why in my comment I told you to always provide an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and not some random pseudo code. If somebody reports a bug in your code you also want to know how to reproduce it.

So in order to reproduce a problem like the one you reported, I have to make an educated guess because your code is not helpful. Just change the following in the previous version:

- `int bMethod(int a, int b, int c)` → `final int bMethod(int a, int b, int c)`
- `Mock(CalcIntf)` → `Mock(Calc)` in 2 places

Now the test result is: one passing and one failing feature method:

```
Condition not satisfied:

math.m2() == 456
|    |    |
|    6    false
...
```

Comment: The sample code was never meant to be a complete compilable & runnable code. apologies for the confusion. however, the only significant point is that out of two methods on the same interface & implementation class, one gets mocked but other does not. final keyword is not involved. There is no difference between the two methods except the argument list and the exception list, and of course the method names which are different. I haven't been able to dig deep yet. probably i'll try today. thanks.

Comment: If it was never meant to be runnable, what was it meant to be? There is obviously information missing here. Learn how to condense and abstract your real code into something small which still reproduces the problem without disclosing company information. That's a basic developer skill. Nobody can debug pseudo code - or can you? If so, please teach me. And if you don't know the solution to your own problem, don't decide for others what is significant about it.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like

```
given: 'a math with a calculator that always returns 100'
    def calc = Stub(CalcIntf) {
        bMethod(_,_,_) >> 100
    }
    def math = new Math(calc)

when: 'the math is asked to calculate something'
    def result = math.m2()

then: 'it returns 100'
    result == 100
```

Points to note:

- return value pushed onto stub should be what is returned rather than a closure
- you have to set the stub calc in math by either a constructor or otherwise
- the methods you are calling on math take no arguments

Comment: I've simplified the code. So, the weird thing happening is that one method is subbed correctly but other method is not, both being in the same class & interface. Also, to note, the only difference between the method signatures is the method name & argument list. I can see the cglib proxy is created in both cases.

Comment: Hi Prakash, to be honest, by editing the code in your question it means much of what I mentioned in the answer doesn't make sense anymore and also you may have hidden the cause of the issue. It does seem weird, and I was going to run the code tomorrow when I have my laptop at hand, but can't see the code now. If you can share the full code again I'll have a look (in UK time)

Comment: Hi Chris, sorry for that. but, its not the actual code, it was just a representation. About not returning closure, the actual method where i am seeing the issue returns something like List<SomeClass>, and the stubbing works for one method but fails for another. It has left me in a tizzy.

Comment: Ah, well if you can share the complete code that would be handy. In the original post, as far as I could see there was no way either test could call the Stub as Math was creating an instance of (real) Calc and nothing was changing that to a Stub. Hence it's quite possible that the problem is not visible in the code currently shared - I guess you have shared the bits of code that you assume must contain the problem, but that would be a big assumption.

Comment: Sharing the actual code is not possible. I'll dig deep into the proxy/aop and see if i can figure out.

Comment: _"Sharing the actual code is not possible."_ **Lazy answer!** Who needs the actual code? What we need is a reproducer. It is called an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I can see your original code because I have enough privilege to see your edit history. That original version had more detail than the current one, even though it was full of bugs. Why did you not edit the original version in order to reproduce the problem instead of removing most of the code? Like this, nobody can find out what is wrong with your code.